# Where does filezilla server store its users data?

Tags: ftp

What I mean is username and passwords.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try looking at `FileZilla Server.xml` in your install directory.

Comment: thanks, that's correct. another question, my filezilla server somehow doesn't read this file, how to apply this settings to current filezilla server?

Comment: Ask a new question as a new question, don't add more questions to an existing question.

Comment: done: http://serverfault.com/questions/209712/filezilla-server-xml-is-not-recognized

Comment: Anyone have the correct answer to this? Changes to the FileZilla Server.xml file are not read in, even after restarting the service.

Answer (score 3):

In current FileZilla-Versions look into `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla`. The `sitemanager.xml` inside this folder contains the wanted information. For migration, it is possbible to copy the whole FileZilla-Folder from one Windows installation to another (or one Windows user to another).

Comment: I believe that's where the **client** stores its data, not the server.

Comment: @ColinO'Dell You're right, of course. Should I delete this answer?

Comment: I'm not sure, because it might be helpful to list both the server and client password locations on the same page like this, just in case somebody stumbles across here looking for your answer.  Whatever you think is best :)

Answer (score 0):

For the serveur version it is in AppData\Local\filezilla-server-gui\settings.xml  in current version of filezilla server.