# FileZilla server.xml is not recognized?

Tags: ftp

I have a Filezilla server.xml which contains all users but somehow the Filezilla server doesn't read it, users are empty, etc. I've tried to use /reload-config with no luck.

Should I re-install Filezilla server?

Comment: How did you add the users ?

Comment: the users were there from the beginning, as part of WebsitePanel using FileZilla as FTP service, but suddenly they're gone, all users, groups are gone, I have no idea what has happened, logs do not explain either.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the corresponding Windows service, and it is not pointing to the correct Filezilla server, strange, it is pointing to another Filezilla server which resides in temp directory under users folder.